# To find the equation of curve.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

We have given a differential equation we have to find the equation of curve. I tried it a lot but not able to proceed. Can someone give me some hints.

$(1-xy+x^2y^2)~dx=x^2~dy$

I tried to substitute $xy=t$ but got no result. Please help.

Comment: did you try $z=\frac{1}{y}$

Comment: @AbdallahHammam how do you get to know we have to substitue this

Comment: cause there is $dy$  and $y^2$ in the equation.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam there are also $x^2$ and dx

Comment: $x$ is the variable and $y$ is the unknown function.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam so whenever we subtitute we only substitute y.

Comment: generally yes, but for some partial differential equations, we change variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1-xy+x^2y^2)~dx=x^2~dy$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{x^2}-\dfrac{y}{x}+y^2$

Let $y=-\dfrac{1}{u}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{u^2}\dfrac{du}{dx}$

$\therefore\dfrac{1}{u^2}\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{1}{xu}+\dfrac{1}{u^2}$

$\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{u^2}{x^2}+\dfrac{u}{x}+1$

Let $v=\dfrac{u}{x}$ ,

Then $u=xv$

$\dfrac{du}{dx}=x\dfrac{dv}{dx}+v$

$\therefore x\dfrac{dv}{dx}+v=v^2+v+1$

$x\dfrac{dv}{dx}=v^2+1$

$\dfrac{dv}{v^2+1}=\dfrac{dx}{x}$

$\int\dfrac{dv}{v^2+1}=\int\dfrac{dx}{x}$

$\tan^{-1}v=\ln x+c$

$v=\tan(\ln x+c)$

$\dfrac{u}{x}=\tan(\ln x+c)$

$-\dfrac{1}{xy}=\tan(\ln x+c)$

$y=-\dfrac{\cot(\ln x+c)}{x}$

$y=\dfrac{\cot(-\ln x-c)}{x}$

$y=\dfrac{\tan(\ln x+C)}{x}$

Comment: How do you get to know what we have to substitute